# Do you need to purchase Experience Cloud in order to create Experience Cloud sites (Digital Experiences)?

Tags: experience-cloud, microsites

From what I can gather, one *doesn't* need to purchase Salesforce Experience Cloud licenses in order to create a Experience Cloud site (aka Community Site) *provided* that you don't require certain templates that are only included in an Experience Cloud, such as the [Microsite Template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_microsites_lwr.htm&type=5) and that you don't require contacts/users to login.

Is that correct?

The semantics are quite confusing because the name 'Community Sites' would be indicative that this feature is exclusively available for Experience Cloud but that doesn't seem to be true because an org only on the Sales Cloud, as an example, could create a Community Site (up to 100, in fact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you get up to 100 community sites included with most editions (I say "most" as I'm not up to date with all the latest editions SF have come out with, but Enterprise and up I know for sure).

As you say, if you want things like logged in users, etc, then these are paid extras.

Comment: OK thanks - I just found https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5 which reads 'In Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited orgs, you can create up to 100 Experience Cloud sites without buying communities licenses. However, you do need to purchase licenses to use specific templates and functionality. For example, to create sites using the Partner Central template, you must purchase at least one Partner Community license. You must have an active community license in your org to use the Archive Site functionality.'